# Add tag to favorites or ignored lists by right-clicking

Tags: feature-request, ignored-tags

I'd like to add a tag to my list of favorite or ignored tags by right-clicking.

Right now, I have to write them manually in a paper, navigate to my preferences and then add them there.

Or, it would be also nice if I could filter questions to show only those ones related to my favorite tags.

Comment: What's "ones" ?

Comment: Question ones :-)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can do this *by left clicking instead*:

- Mouse over the tag until the info box pops up.

  [image: tag info box]
- Click on the grey star, turning it yellow.

  [image: starred equals favourited]
- Click on the yellow star, it'll be replaced by a red check box.

  [image: crossed equals ignored]

Voila, you added the tag to your *ignored* list.

Note that you can also add ignored tags in the sidebar; no need to navigate to your pretences for this at all.  Click on the *edit* link next to the *Favourite Tags* header and you get to edit both favourite and ignored tags right there:

[image: Favourite tags edit link]

Comment: oh boy... the little star... thx

Comment: This has very poor discoverability.  Is there any other star on the site that has a connotation of *negative* favoriting?

Comment: Agree to @BenVoigt. I wouldn't have discovered it on my own.